How do I get u-boot to boot a signed (non-Linux) firmware image on my AM64x?
I have a working system, based on the EVM board for the TI Sitara AM64x.
It is running u-boot 2024.04, compiled from the TI SDK 10 and can boot my ELF file containing my app and threatX OS using the bootelfcommand of u-boot.
But I want to start using signed firmware images.
From what I could find, I understand that u-boot only supports that using FIT images and the bootmcommand.
I tried creating a super simple FIT image like this (for now without even signing it!):
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    description = "Simple FIT image with threatx OS firmware";
    #address-cells = <1>;

    images {
        firmware {
            description = "threatx OS Firmware";
            data = /incbin/("./threatx_firmware.elf");
            type = "firmware";
            arch = "arm64";
            os = "firmware";
            compression = "none";
            load = <0x90000000>;
            entry = <0x90000000>;
            hash {
                algo = "sha256";
            };
        };
    };

    configurations {
        default = "conf";
        conf {
            description = "Boot threatx OS firmware";
            firmware = "firmware";
        };
    };
};

but u-boot always complains about not finding a "kernel" entry when trying to boot this with bootm.
When I imxtract the ELF from there and start it with bootelfit works fine again. But I need to verify the signature down the road, so bootmis my only option, I guess?
Am I on the completely wrong track?
Trying to objcopy the ELF into a flat binary also did not yield the results I was looking for because bootm does not even try to load the image
Any help appreciated

So, "firmware" has a special meaning and that's why that doesn't work. I suspect the overall answer is that no one has added support for booting an ELF file out of a FIT image at this time.

I would even prefer a flat plain binary created from the ELF via objcpy. But still u-boot doesn't even begin to start that and instead complains. So any hint on how to get this to work would be appreciated

You need to write the plumbing so that an ELF file is recognized in a FIT image and started.
